# Get element width with right unit

Tags: html, css

Is possible to get "10vw" for the element width in browser or extension.Chrome "Copy Styles" just works fine.But I wanna do it in an extension.

[Source code for chrome devtools](https://github.com/ChromeDevTools/devtools-frontend/blob/master/front_end/elements/ElementsTreeElement.js#L1756)

[image: chrome copy styles just works fine]

```html
<style>
  div { width: 10em }
  body div { width: 10em }
  #id { width: 10vw }
</style>

<div id="dom"></div>
```

```js
// if viewport width is 375px

var dom = document.getElementById('app');
var style = window.getComputedStyle(dom);

var width = style.getPropertyValue('width');

console.log(width) // 37.5px, "10vw" would be great
```

Comment: I don't understand, is it not working? What result are you expecting? That would give you 10% of the view-port's current width. Is it not what you want?

Comment: Are you trying to query the elements width in Javascript and get the result in `vw` instead of the default `px`?

Comment: I want "10vw" to be returned , the result i get with "window.getComputedStyle" is "37.5px" if viewport width is 375px.

Comment: Maybe the unit i use in css is not "vw", it could be "em" or "rem" or something else.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element

Comment: Is good, but not work for <link rel="stylesheet" href="..." />

Answer (score 1):

```
var element = document.getElementById('dom')
var elementWidth = getComputedStyle(element ).width
```

this will always return width with pixels.
hope this will be helpfull